# Javascript check if mouse is over one of several elements

Tags: javascript, hover, element

So I have several elements in a page that I want to behave in the same way when hovered (I specifically want to change their class). Instead of adding a onmouseover listener to all of them one by one, is there a more efficient or cleaner solution?

I tried using onmousemove with e.target, but the problem is I have nested elements and sometimes it often targets the wrong one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, use CSS [`:hover`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:hover).

Comment: try `e.currentTarget`

Comment: build a (web) component?

Comment: @Tushar, how can I use css to toggle a class?

Comment: @charlietfl, e.currentTarget just returns document (I'm using document.onmousemove)

Comment: @manonthemat, how do I build a web component?